# Why is the angle always acute by taking the absolute value of the dot product divided by the product of the vectors magnitudes?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I can derive the dot product formula from the law of cosines and also show the algebraic equivalence but I cannot understand why $\cos ( \theta ) = \frac{|\mathbb{u} \cdot \mathbb{v}|}{||\mathbb{u}||||\mathbb{v}||}$ will always be acute by placing absolute values around the dot product. There must be a simple view I am missing.

Comment: The numerator is the dot product, *not* the absolute value: $\,\cos \theta = \cfrac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\Vert u \Vert \,\Vert v \Vert}\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because for acute angles $x$ we have $|\cos x|=\cos x$.

On the other hand, for ${\pi\over2}<x\le\pi$, we have $\cos x<0$ and $|\cos x|=-\cos x=\cos(\pi-x)$.

This answer assumes that we are using the formula
$$
\mbox{angle }x = \arccos \frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\Vert u \Vert \,\Vert v \Vert}
$$
as compared to
$$
\mbox{angle }x = \arccos \frac{|\langle u,v\rangle|}{\Vert u \Vert \,\Vert v \Vert}.
$$
Note that $\langle u,v\rangle = \Vert u \Vert \,\Vert v \Vert \cos x$,
where $x$ is the angle formed by $u$ and $v$.